# Convert Coldfusion to PHP find('filename.cfm', cgi.script_name)

Tags: php, coldfusion

I am working on rewriting a Coldfusion script to a PHP script and I have never worked with either language. I am partway through with the conversion but I have run into part of the cf script that I am stuck on rewriting in PHP.

```
<cfset i_pos = find('index.cfm',cgi.script_name)>
<cfif i_pos GT 0>
    <cfset s = RemoveChars(cgi.script_name,i_pos,9)>
<cfelse>
    <cfset s = s = cgi.script_name>
</cfif>
```

I understand that 'find' will look for the first occurence of a substring but it appears that we are working with a file that gets the virtual path from cgi.script_name. 
I was thinking that I could use the following for php but I don't think it will work.

```
$filepath=dirnmae(__FILE__)
$i_pos = strstr('index.cfm', $filepath)
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: If you look at the value of $filepath in php, is it similar to cgi.script_name in coldfusion?

Comment: How does `SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]` in PHP compare to CF's `CGI.SCRIPT_NAME`?

Comment: Red Flag Hat on again. My question is: If you have never worked with either language, why are you doing a conversion? There are a lot of nuances that you may miss. Having done a few conversions the other way (PHP to CF), CF is much more terse, so there may be a lot of things that won't translate because CF does them behind the scenes.

Comment: RE: This question: Are you simply trying to strip `index.cfm` out of the `cgi.script_name`?   What is the context of this code?

Comment: Are you sure that a php code in a file called `index.cfm` will actually execute?

Comment: After re-reading, I came across a bit ruder than I intended. I wasn't trying to disparage your skills. But since you said you didn't know either language, my Red Flag Alert went off because there can be a lot of risk for your company here. If I was asked to convert a C app to Smalltalk, I'd have to push back (after 20 years of dev, I know neither). Part of being a dev is recognizing that the perceived benefits of "upgrades" sometimes don't outweigh the risks. And I can't say how many times I've watched a "Convert CF to X" go _horribly_ off the rails even when experienced CF devs were included.

Comment: `__FILE__` is the name of the `.php` file where your currently running code resides. ColdFusion's `CGI.SCRIPT_NAME` is the requested URL as seen by the webserver. Maybe the webserver did a translation to a file on the file system. As @Alex points out: `SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]` is a good try.